# Combining css3 and canvas renderers

Tags: css, canvas, three.js, renderer

I am bound to use IE10, so no WebGL, please :)

Using two different Three.js examples, I've created two different scenes, using two different renderers, etc...

Using the css3d_periodictable.html example, I am rendering a scene with a css3drenderer.

Using the canvas_particles_random.html example, I am rendering a different scene with a canvas renderer.

By now, both are in different HTML files. I would love to combine them.

The canvas renderer is needed because I want to use its power to "fly" thousands of different background 'items'. Independently, I want to 'fly' only a few CSS controlled foreground items. So I would like to either combine the different items into the same scenes, using different renderers and cameras for them. Or I would like to "overlay" the CSS3 rendered scene in front of the canvas rendered background layer. Is that possible and what do I need to take into account for that?

Comment: Did you see http://threejs.org/examples/css3d_sandbox.html?

Comment: No, I did not inspect that code (since there's no animation in it :-)). I can see that the same camera is being used. That's fantastic. I think I can go from there... Very nice.

Comment: this is an integration of canvas and dom elements might be of some help... http://blog.dewmap.com/post/50c68dfbe16b160200000001